# How to prove convexity of a given set

Tags: convex-analysis

I have the set

$$
C_c = \{(x,y,z) \epsilon \mathbb{R}^3 : (2x-x^2+y)(2y-3z)(5x-z) > 1, |x| < 1, y > 3, z < 2\}
$$

and I need to prove whether it's convex or not. I know that the intersection of different convex sets is convex, but the first inequality is not a convex set (from plotting it). However, the whole set seems to be. What basically makes it convex is the restriction on the values of y (I think). But I don't know how to go about proving that it is convex.

Comment: It might help to include a picture of the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's focus on that first inequality. We note four things:

*First:* all three terms are *concave* functions of $x$, $y$, and $z$. The second and third terms are affine, of course, but it is their concavity we need here.

*Second:* the first two terms are *positive* when the other inequalities are satisfied. For the first term, it helps to note that $2x-x^2+y=y+1-(x-1)^2$. The second term is relatively simple to verify as well.

*Third:* the third term *must* be positive as well. Unlike the first two terms, this does not immediately follow from the other inequalities. But since the first two terms of the product are positive, the *only* way the inequality can be satisfied is if the third term is positive as well.

*Fourth:* the inequality is equivalent to
$$\sqrt[3]{(2x-x^2+y)(2y-3z)(5x-z)}>1.$$
The left-hand site is now a geometric mean of concave, positive terms. The geometric mean is a concave, *non-decreasing* function of positive arguments. Nonlinear composition rules for convex optimization (see, for instance, Section 3.2.4 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization*) tell us that the composition of a concave, nondecreasing outer function and concave inner functions is concave. So the entire left-hand side is a concave function
of $x$, $y$, and $z$ whenever those terms are positive.

Therefore, this product inequality takes the form $f(x,y,z)>1$, where $f$ is a concave function of $x,y,z$. This describes a concave set.

If we need a bit more rigor, we can define the following extended-valued function:
$$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{(2x-x^2+y)(2y-3z)(5x-z)} & |x|<1,~y>3,~z<2,~5x-z>0 
\\ -\infty & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
This function has a convex domain, and is concave on that domain, for all of the reasons we have argued above. Then $C_c$ is described by a single inequality involving this concave function:
$$C_c=\{(x,y,z)\,|\,f(x,y,z)>1\}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this really clarifies a lot of things. One more thing to ask, I was under the impression that affine functions are convex. Is that not always true?

Comment: Affine functions are both convex and concave.